# npm install MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: reactjs

During npm install I get several of the following warning message:

(node:5156) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxLis
teners() to increase limit
(node:5156) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxLis
teners() to increase limit
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-10T15_52_29_865Z-debug-0.log

install npm and dependences